# Inserting value inside list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a problem with the lists of list that I have right now.

Let say I have the following information:

```
path = [['B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'],['C', 'B'], 'A']
index = [0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14]
```

This data means that at time index = 0, my observation is B. At time index = 3, my observation is C, and so on. It should be noted that I would like to keep the data structure to be lists of list, as this means that I have 3 distinct set of observations throughout time = 0 until time = 14. The first Observation is from time 0 until time 9, and so on.

What I am actually trying to do is to complete the lists of list. Meaning, I would like to add my observation inside the lists of list (path). For all time that is missing ( 1, 2, 4, 7... does not exists at index), I would like to add that particular observation to my lists of list (path). This observation will be similar to the previous observation. Thus, at time t = 1, my observation will be B (Observation at time = 0). At time = 2, my observation will be B(Observation at time = 1), and so on.

The end result that I am hoping to get from this is:

```
complete_path = [['B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'C', 'B', 'B','B'],'A']
```

I think I can solve this question if it is a list, but I find this to be difficult for lists of list. Your kind help will be appreciated. Have a nice day!

Edited:

There are two more conditions to this problem:
1. Sometimes, the `path` might be a regular list, not a nested list. Thus, we need to take note that possibility.
2. if the last observation is just a single value, it will resulted in a string instead of list. Other than that case, `path` will always be nested list.

Here are the working code that I have created. It looks really messy, and I hope that anyone are able to enlighten me whether its possible to solve this problem in a better way / fewer lines of code.

```
def complete_list(list_, index, max_index = None):
    if max_index == None:
        max_index = max(index)
    complete_list = [None]*((max_index + 1) - min(index))
    complete_list[0] = list_.pop(0)
    for true_index in range(min(index) + 1, max_index + 1):
        if true_index in index:
            complete_list[true_index - min(index)] = list_.pop(0)
        else:
            complete_list[true_index - min(index)] = complete_list[true_index - min(index) - 1]
    return complete_list

def is_lists_of_list(lists):
    return np.any([isinstance(y, list) for y in lists])

def get_first_index(lists_of_list):
    list_first_index = [0]*len(lists_of_list)
    for i in range(1,len(lists_of_list)):
        if isinstance(lists_of_list, list):
            list_first_index[i] = len(lists_of_list[i-1]) + list_first_index[i-1]
    return list_first_index

def complete_lists_of_list(lists_of_list, index, max_index):
    result = []
    n_lists = len(lists_of_list)
    list_first_index = [index[x] for x in get_first_index(lists_of_list)]
    for i in range(n_lists - 1):
        used_index = [ x for x in index if (x >= list_first_index[i]) and (x < list_first_index[i+1])]
        tmp_result = complete_list(list(lists_of_list[i]), used_index, max_index=list_first_index[i+1] - 1)
        result.append(tmp_result)
    if isinstance(lists_of_list[-1],list):
        used_index = [x for x in index if x >= list_first_index[n_lists] and x <= max_index]
        tmp_result = complete_list(list(lists_of_list[n_lists]), used_index)
        result.append(tmp_result)
    else:
        tmp_result = [lists_of_list[-1]] * (max_index - index[-1] + 1)
        result.append(tmp_result)
    return result

def smoothen_path(object, index, max_index):
    if is_lists_of_list(object):
        return complete_lists_of_list(object, index, max_index)
    else:
        return complete_list(object, index, max_index)
```

Comment: what did you done to make this so far?

Comment: 0 effort = no help

Comment: When adding an entry for index 13, should the item go in the outer list, just before the last `A`, or at the end of the second inner list just after the `B`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That duplicate, while having a very similar title, seems to be about an entirely different problem.

Comment: @tobias_k On closer inspection, I did close this in haste. If OP can expand upon what they've done and where they went wrong, this would become a legitimate question. As it stands, this is too broad... feel free to reopen.

Comment: If this was just regularly nested (lists in lists) this would be relatively simple, finding the "repeats" from the "indices" and making an iterator/generator from those. With mixed lists and strings it gets more complicated. Also, how often should the final element appear?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I would like to apologize for posing a question without giving my current solution to this problem. I have attached my current solution in this post. Hopefully you can give me better insights on tackling this problem efficiently. Cheers!

Comment: @quamrana it should be at the second inner list just after the `B` :)

Comment: @tanaydin I have attached my current solution in my edited post. Cheers

Comment: @tobias_k I have added the conditions about the final element in the post. Let me know if my explanation is not clear enough. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a recursive function, taking how often to repeat the current element from a iterator, and passing that same iterator to the recursive calls used for nested lists.

```
def repeat(path, repeats):
    return [x for y in path for x in 
            ([repeat(y, repeats)] if isinstance(y, list) else [y] * next(repeats))]
```

To create the `repeats` iterator, you can use `zip` to get pairs of consecutive elements in `index`, but you need to add another element how often to repeat the last element (i.e. the total length of the resulting list and its sublists).

```
path = [['B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'],['C', 'B'], 'A']
index = [0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14]

index += [16] # end of list
repeats = (b-a for (a,b) in zip(index, index[1:]))

res = repeat(path, repeats)
```

For this example, `res` would be `[['B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'A', 'A']`